# UINavigation Controller - Back Button Pop to a certain UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, transition, back

Let's say we've got a few `UIViewControllers` on the stack of our `UINavigationController`

How can I define the `UIViewController` (instead of the previous one) the back button should pop to? (so basically pop two or more instead of one)
Maybe I want the back button to pop back to the root view controller, or just 2 view controllers before.

I know I could create a custom left bar button, but that looses the nice leftwards arrow in the button. And I don't want to use a png graphic to get that arrow back.

Edit:

I want to know how to pop to a certain UIViewController when pressing the back button in the navigation bar. I know how to pop to a certain controller, but not how to have the back button do it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  Are you wanting to know how to customize the action of the back button, or are you wanting to know how to pop multiple items from a navigation controller?  The title indicates the latter, but the last paragraph implies the former.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing the viewControllers push all the ones that you may want to go back to and then use `popToViewController:animated:` to go back to the one that you want. Or use `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to go back all the way to the `rootViewController`.

Comment: Yes, but how to do this when pressing the back button on the navigation bar? It should look exactly like a standard back button (with maybe custom text).

Comment: @Max I see. A possible solution could be to make a subclass of UINavigationController class and override the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method to have your custom code. Haven't tested it though to see if it works as expected.

Comment: Yeah that could work and I read of it but that isn't really are nice solution. Since I have to check for every single pop then.

Comment: @Max You will only need to implement a custom code when you don't want to go back to the previous VC. Otherwise you can just call the `[super popViewControllerAnimate:]`.